# Same Form for Creating and Editing Data in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a reactive form to create and insert data into a database but I have problems editing a row. Firstly I have to create a route in routing module and give it direction (like `path: 'patient/:id', component: PatientComponent`. here /patient is my main page).

Secondly, when I click on the edit button, it loads the form with related data but as I click on the submit button, the specific row does not edit but a new record with a new `$key` is added to the table instead.

I want to click on the edit button and the form not to load (omit `/patient/{{patient.$key}}`) and it should modify the data in the database when I click the submit button.

Thank You...

[image]

Here's my component code:

```
patientIdUpdate = null; 

ngOnInit() {  
    this.updatePatientData();
    const id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
    this.crudApi.GetPatient(id).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
    this.patientForm.setValue(data)
    })

    this.crudApi.GetPatientsList();
    this.patientsForm(); 
    this.dataState();
    let s = this.crudApi.GetPatientsList(); 
    s.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.Patient = [];
      data.forEach(item => {
        let a = item.payload.toJSON(); 
        a['$key'] = item.key;
        this.Patient.push(a as Patient);
      })
    })
  }

dataState() {     
    this.crudApi.GetPatientsList().valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.preLoader = false;
      if(data.length <= 0){
        this.hideWhenNoPatient = false;
        this.noData = true;
      } else {
        this.hideWhenNoPatient = true;
        this.noData = false;
      }
    })
  }

submitPatientData(patient: Patient) {
    if(this.patientIdUpdate == null) {
    this.crudApi.AddPatient(this.patientForm.value);
    this.router.navigate(['patient']);
    this.ResetForm();
    } else {
    patient.$key = this.patientIdUpdate
    this.crudApi.UpdatePatient(this.patientForm.value);  
    this.router.navigate(['patient']);
    this.ResetForm();    
    }

   };
```

And here is my markup code:

```
<form [formGroup]="patientForm" (ngSubmit)="submitPatientData()">

<tr *ngFor="let patient of Patient | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 7, currentPage: p }; let i = index;">
              <td class="text-center action-block">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" routerLink="/patient/{{patient.$key}}"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" (click)="deletePatient(patient)"></i></button></td>
              <td>{{patient.FirstName}} {{patient.LastName}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.FatherName}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.Address}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.NC}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.Mobile}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.Date}}</td>
              <td>{{patient.Reason | number}}</td>
```

Comment: It's generally polite to provide simplified examples so readers don't have to parse through a lot of extra content to get to the heart of the question.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to check your service where you're calling

```
this.crudApi.UpdatePatient(this.patientForm.value);
```

Is it using the `PUT` method?